# Reference style links immediately following tag links are broken

Tags: bug, markdown

### The problem

It seems that if a reference style link (`[text][url]`) follows a tag link (`[tag:foo]`) then the reference style link  break.  Example:

#### Inline link following a tag link (unbroken)

```
[tag:a-tag] [in-line link](http://example.org/)
```

[a-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/a-tag) [inline link](http://example.org/)

#### Reference link following a tag link (with just one space) (broken)

```
[tag:a-tag] [reference link][1]

  [1]: http://example.org/
```

[a-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/a-tag) [reference link][1](http://example.org/another)

#### Reference link following a tag link (with multiple spaces) (unbroken)

```
[tag:a-tag]  [reference link][1]

  [1]: http://example.org/
```

[a-tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/a-tag)  [reference link](http://example.org/another)

### Relevant Specifications

#### Gruber's Markdown

After noticing the "one space" vs. "two space" issue, I looked at [the documentation for "standard" Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link) (i.e., not necessarily "Stack Overflow flavored Markdown"), which says:

> Reference-style links use a second set of square brackets, inside
>   which you place a label of your choosing to identify the link:
>
> ```
> This is [an example][id] reference-style link.
> ```
>
> You can optionally use a space to separate the sets of brackets:
>
> ```
> This is [an example] [id] reference-style link.
> ```

I guess that means that this isn't necessarily a bug, since the Markdown is ambiguous.  However, it does seem that the output produced is a bit odd.  If it's trying to take `tag:a-tag` as link text and `reference link` as the URL, why is `reference link` displayed *with* its brackets, and why is `1` a link?

#### CommonMark

On the other hand, as [Braiam notes in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318273/reference-style-links-immediately-following-tag-links-are-broken?noredirect=1#comment317404_318273), the CommonMark specification explicitly disallows space between the text and the link, as shown in [Example 499](http://spec.commonmark.org/0.23/#example-499):

> No whitespace is allowed between the link text and the link label:
>   [examples] This is a departure from John Gruber’s original Markdown
>   syntax description, which explicitly allows whitespace between the
>   link text and the link label. It brings reference links in line with
>   inline links, which (according to both original Markdown and this
>   spec) cannot have whitespace after the link text. More importantly, it
>   prevents inadvertent capture of consecutive shortcut reference links.
>   If whitespace is allowed between the link text and the link label,
>   then in the following we will have a single reference link, not two
>   shortcut reference links, as intended:

Comment: @CodyGray just noticed that too and updated.

Comment: @CodyGray Actually, now that I think of it, at least one markdown spec might mention that behavior (allowing a space between link text and the URL). Maybe this isn't a bug...

Comment: Oh, the markdown doc at https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link says that a space is permitted.  I guess this isn't a bug according to that spec, then.

Comment: Oh, the markdown doc at daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#link says that a space is permitted. I guess this isn't necessarily a bug according to that spec, then, but a weird interaction between Stack Overflow-flavored Markdown (with its tag links) and the syntax in standard Markdown.

Comment: Commonmark spec doesn't define this case http://spec.commonmark.org/0.23, actually it is http://spec.commonmark.org/0.23/#example-499 "No whitespace is allowed between the link text and the link label"